# download.file in R using wget

Tags: r, curl, wget

The webpage I am trying to access downloads an attachment but header status is always 500 which I have checked through postman.

I am using `download.file` with `wget` method in R to download that file but it stops and doesn't download since the header status is 500. How can I manage to download this file irrespective of the header status?

When I access this link in browser, the file is downloaded just fine.

Edit:

Here's how I use download.file function in R:

```
  download.file(get(url), destfile=tmpFile, method = "wget");
```

I tried to pass the extra argument like:

```
 download.file(get(url), destfile=tmpFile, method = "wget", extra =getOption("content-on-error"));
```

and

```
  download.file(get(url), destfile=tmpFile, method = "wget", extra =getOption("--content-on-error=0"));
```

but it doesn't work

Here :

`get(url)` points to the link:

```
https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=__KEY__&reports=AllCampaignsSummary,AllCampaignsChart,AllAds,AllCampaignsSites&start_date=01-01-2013&end_date=10-05-2016&format=csv&currency=USD
```

message on trying to connect:

```
Resolving app.adroll.com... 52.11.56.178, 52.89.249.63
Connecting to app.adroll.com|52.11.56.178|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2016-10-06 16:22:21 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

Comment: What about `library(httr);r <- GET("http://httpbin.org/get");bin <- content(r, "raw");writeBin(bin, "myfile.txt")`?

Comment: @lukeA: It gives Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  SSL connect error

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q="httr"++"SSL+connect+error"+curl%3A%3Acurl_fetch_memory(url%2C+handle+%3D+handle) ?

Comment: I found out about --content-on-error option in wget. It downloads on error as well. Could you help me find out how to pass this to download.file please?

Comment: Looks like you got to put it into the `extra` argument. Can you provide the full `download.file` command that you are trying?

Comment: @lukeA: Hey, updated :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125094/discussion-between-lukea-and-gags).

Comment: What `url` do you use? What about `download.file("http...", destfile=tf <- tempfile(), method = "wget", extra ="--content-on-error=0")`?

Comment: @lukeA: Updated the question with info. Please check

Comment: I get an error, no file, when calling the URL in a browser. Your problem might lie a bit deeper and `download.file` might not be the thing you are looking for. Maybe have a look at introductions to the `httr` and `rvest` packages.

Comment: @lukeA: There is no "key" in the url I posted so you were not able to access it.I can assure it works and downlads the file just fine in browser. Should I post it along?

Comment: download.file definitely works for me.Certainly. Only if I can get the extra options passed correctly.